# Оптимизация кода и обратное действие

Tags: jquery, javascript

Только начинаю изучать Jquery, и думается мне, что код слишком кривой и объёмный.
Задача по клику на объект (`span.calc`) внутри блока `div.product` добавлять новый класс этому блоку, а также менять текст у `span.calc` и его класс. Плюс следующий блок за нашим `div.product` должен принимать класс `next`, это нужно для его позиционирования.

Визуально выглядит так:

https://yadi.sk/i/DNarvfUWavH9t

Код ниже, открытие по клику работает, классы тоже все, как надо. Вопрос в кривизне кода.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("span.calc").click(function() {
            $("div.product").removeClass("open next"); // закрываем все открытые блоки
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().toggleClass("open"); // задаём для div.product дополнительный класс open
            $(this).text("Свернуть"); // меняем текст у span.calc на «Свернуть»
            $(this).addClass("open"); // добавляем класс open для span.calc 
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().next("div.product").addClass("next"); // добавляем класс next для следующего div.product
        });

  });
  </script>
```

Попинайте, плз.

И основной вопрос: как сделать обратное действие по клику (закрытие блока)? Пробовал писать так:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("span.calc").click(function() {
            $("div.product").removeClass("open next"); 
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().toggleClass("open");
            $(this).text("Свернуть"); 
            $(this).addClass("open"); 
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().next("div.product").addClass("next");
        });
        $("span.calc.open").click(function() {
            $("div.product").removeClass("open next"); 
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().toggleClass("open");
            $(this).text("Рассчитать"); 
            $(this).removeClass("open");
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().next("div.product").removeClass("next");
        });
  });
  </script>
```

Не работает.

Comment: Сделайте jsfiddle с разметкой, по второму вопросу понятно, чего делать надо - можно, например, сделать on() вместо click.

    $(document).on("click","span.calc.open",function(){/* --- */})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так можно сделать:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("span.calc").click(function () {
        var product = $(this).parents('div.product').first(), //div.product 
            isopen = !product.hasClass('open'); //открываем ?
        product.removeClass('next').toggleClass("open") //у себя убрать .next, переключить open
             //у соседних продуктов убрать .next и .open поставить текст Рассчитать на кнопки
            .siblings('div.product').removeClass("open next").find('span.calc').text('Рассчитать'); 
        //у своей кнопки сделать текст Свернуть/Рассчитать
        $(this).text(isopen ? "Свернуть" : "Рассчитать"); 
        //если открываем, добавить .next к следующему продукту
        if (isopen) product.next("div.product").addClass("next"); 
    });
});
```

Обратите внимание, что для упрощения кода я немого поменял css:

было:

```
.content .product div.calc span.calc.open
```

стало:

```
.content .product.open div.calc span.calc
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/58aqkhe0/3/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и комментарии в коде, теперь всё, как надо =)

Comment: Я бы еще вот так сделал: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/58aqkhe0/4/, тогда продукты можно по ходу пьесы добавлять:

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/58aqkhe0/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(id).toggle(
function(){
//открываете
},
function(){
//закрываете
}
)
```

Comment: Не врубаюсь, а что есть id, куда воткнуть мой span.calc?

Comment: [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), отменили уже

> Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

Comment: Да, и зачем мне toogle для моей кнопки, если он даёт display: none

<span class="calc" style="display: none;">Рассчитать</span>

Мне надо менять классы этому span и другим элементам туда-сюда по клику.

Comment: @Detonator, в старых jQuery toggle работало примерно так:

    var functions=[function1,function2];
    $(element).click(function(e) {
       var f=functions.shift();
       functions.push(f);
       f.call(this,e);
    });

Т.е. на каждый клик меняло поведение между двумя функциями.

Сделайте fiddle, и я вам дам нормальный ответ. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/o6j6hw65/ вот сюда разметку добавьте, нажмите save и дайте  ссылку.

Comment: @eicto, в целом практически понятно.
Но как быть с задачей закрытия, почему не работает моя версия?

Comment: @Detonator, потому что span с классами open и calc на момент вызова .click() нет.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/58aqkhe0/ как-то так.